# Clarification regarding nested groups in regex

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression: "Jan 1987" that I want it spliced into two groups:

1. The first group should match the whole string
2. The second group should match only the year

The following expression: `(.+(\d+))` creates the first group but the second group only matches the the last digit, if I add a space like this `(.+ (\d+))` the second group matches correctly the whole year.

Can someone explain me why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The following expression: (.+(\d+)) creates the first group but the second group only matches the the last digit, if I add a space like this (.+ (\d+)) the second group matches correctly the whole year.
>
> Can someone explain me why?

Yes, because this term `.+` is greedy and will match all the way up until the
last digit which only 1 is really required to then satisfy the whole match.

By adding the space requirement it tells the engine that it has to find
at least a space followed by a digit, which there is only 1 place in the sample,
therefore the Month is matched in the correct group and likewise
the year in its correct group.

Answer (score -1):

The actual regex you most likely want to be using here is something like this:

```
(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (\d{4})
```

If you want to access the entire match, then this is already the whole string.  Depending on the regex tool/language you are using, you could also access the zeroth capture group.  The 4 digit year would be available in the first capture group.

### Demo